# Access every other item in an array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible for me to access every other item in an array? So basically, all items in positions 0, 2, 4, 6 etc.

Here's my code if it helps:

```
function pushToHash(key, value) {
    for (var t = 0; t < value.length; t++) {
    MQHash[key[t]] = value.slice(0, lineLength[t]);
    }
}
```

So, I need to get every other value of `lineLength`. I only want this for `lineLength`, not `key`. I was thinking of doing a modulus, but wasn't sure how I'd implement it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want this with `lineLength` and not with `key`, then add a second variable and use `+=` when incrementing:

```
function pushToHash(key, value) {
    for (var t = 0, x = 0; t < value.length; t++, x += 2) {
        MQHash[key[t]] = value.slice(0, lineLength[x]);
    }
}
```

(The power of the [comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14)...)

Answer (score 31):

You can use the index (second parameter) in the array filter method like this:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// filter out all elements that are located at an even index in the array.

let x = arr.filter((element, index) => {
  return index % 2 === 0;
})

console.log(x) 
// [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about   **for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will truncate an array every X elements (factor).

```
const truncateArray = (array: any[], factor: number): any[] => {
  let lastNumber = 0;
  return array.filter((element, index) => {
    const shouldIncludeThisElement = index === lastNumber + factor ? true : false;
    lastNumber = shouldIncludeThisElement ? index : lastNumber;
    return shouldIncludeThisElement;
  });
};
```